# Creating 3d matrice from 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have two lists of values, **x** and **y**:

```
index = np.arange(-1,1,0.01)
x = index
y = index
```

Out of this list, I want to create a **3d plot**, for this I need **z** which I currently have the following code for:

```
z = []
for i in x:
    temp_list = []
    for i2 in y:
        temp_list.append(-(i**2+i2**2))
    z.append(temp_list)
```

With this data I can generate the following graph:
[image]

**Question:**

How can I generate list z with shape `(len(x), len(y))` **only with numpy** methods and not with this iteration, I am doing in my example?

**+1 for oneliners**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using broadcasting:

```py
import numpy as np

index = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)

Z = -(index[:,None] ** 2 + index[None, :] ** 2)
```

This way you can avoid using `np.meshgrid`. If the axes are not the same, you should use it like this:

```py
Z = -(x_axis[:,None] ** 2 + y_axis[None, :] ** 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to generate the x-y coordinates from `index`:

```py
import numpy as np

index = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(index, index)

z = -(np.square(x) + np.square(y))
```